# Opera: reading Google Groups?

Tags: opera, google-groups, newsreader

Is it possible to read [Google Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Groups) in [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_(web_browser))'s
newsreader? If so, how is it setup?

Platform: Opera 9.64, Windows XP 64 bit SP2, 8 GB RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [not Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=46465):

> Sorry, you can't use a regular newsreader to access our service. You can, however, access Google Groups from most web browsers.

If you want to access Usenet you'll have to see if your ISP runs their own newserver. Or, failing that, a public newgroup server to log into.

For that, you'll need to grab the info and go:

> Tools > Mail and Chat Accounts

To bring up the Manage Accounts dialog.

Click **Add**.

New Account Wizard dialog will pop up.

Select **Newsgroups** and then click **Next**.

Follow the wizard and you're set.

However, even though you'll be hooked into Usenet, you still won't be able to use Google Groups via Opera.

Answer (score 1):

A "regular" Google Group is indeed just a Google Group. But many of the groups that Google calls "Google Groups" are usenet news groups. These can be accessed using any interface that supports usenet news group access.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Wikipedia article on Google Groups that you linked to says it all:

> A regular Google Group is hosted by Google.
>   These groups can be accessed using a
>   web browser or by subscribing to
>   receive email, but can't be accessed
>   using a Usenet news reader.