# Google groups -> newsgroups?

Tags: newsgroups, google-groups

I' news with the **newsgroups**, can we use google groups like a newsgroup (for read in thunderbird for example) ?

Comment: As a similar question for [Opera is on topic](http://superuser.com/q/44112/74311) I don't fully understand why this question is closed (ignoring the improvable wording). `google-groups` has an own tag and I came here with the exact same question and found the answer useful.

Answer (score 4):

A subset of the groups that are available at Google Groups are usenet groups.  While Google does not provide NNTP access (the protocol used by usenet clients such as thunderbird to access groups) to these groups, they can be accessed through any other usenet provider (usenet groups are federated, in that a post to one usenet server gets replicated to all other servers).

These are the groups you can access this way: http://groups.google.com/groups/dir?sel=33604954

Any of Google's private groups are only available via the web interface or any apps that Google might produce to give access.  They cannot be accessed with a standard nntp client like Thunderbird.